# Plotting using multi index values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, multi-index

I have an excel file with the following data:

[image]

My code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt    
df=pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', header=[0,1], index_col=[0])
```

Firstly, am I reading in my file correctly to have a multi index using Main (A,B,C) as the first level and Value (X,Y) as the second level.

Using `Pandas` and `Matplotlib` - how do I plot individual scatter plot for Main (A,B,C) with each x,y as the scatter values (imaged below) . I can do it messily calling each column in an individual plot function.
Is there a nicer way to do it with `multi-indexing` or `group by`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
df = df.set_index(['Main1', 'Main2']).value

df.unstack.plot(kind='line', stacked=True)
```

Comment: I get the following error - NotImplementedError: > 1 ndim Categorical are not supported at this time